# Maximum number of articles allowed in SQL 2008 R2 for merge replication

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Does anyone know of a Microsoft documented limit for the maximum number of articles in merge replication for SQL Server 2008 R2? I have [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) link that specifies the max for SQL 2012 (i think), which is 256, but I need one for 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.105%29).

Under the headline of the linked article is a select field named "other versions". You can use it to directly access the relevant document for 2008R2.